# Ray follow crosshair

Tags: css

I'm trying to let a ray expand from center. How can I expand it to the single side and follow crosshair?
The transform-origin and scale is not working.

fiddle(need to preview in full screen)
https://jsfiddle.net/a5em1cb2/2/

css

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
  border: solid red 1px;
  cursor: url('https://i.imgur.com/qGRHc5C.png') 50 50,crosshair;
}

#clock {
  border: solid blue 1px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.seconds-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  border: solid purple 1px;

  transform-origin: 50% 80%;
}

.seconds {
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;

  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: :scale(40,40);
  width: 1%;
  z-index: 8;

  border: solid yellow 1px;
}
```

html

```
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="1663" height="1052" style="border:1px double #d3d3d3;"></canvas>

<article class="clock" id="clock">
  <div class="seconds-container" id="seconds-container">
    <div class="seconds" id="seconds"></div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/williamqin123/md3ywc16/

---

`width` and `height` are the dimensions of the entire page. This includes area outside of the visible viewport, like when the user's screen is too small to fit the entire canvas. When that happens, the ray's center will be misaligned with `zerox` and `zeroy`.

Change `width` and `height` to be the dimensions of the viewport.

```
// BEFORE
zerox = width/2;
zeroy = height/2;

// AFTER
zerox = document.body.clientWidth/2;
zeroy = document.body.clientHeight/2;
```

---

Remove useless line.

```
transform: :scale(40,40); // I don't know what this is supposed to do. Correct me in the comments if it has a real purpose.
```

---

The 90-degrees offset is in the wrong direction. Invert it!

```
90+(salopeInRadian * 180) / Math.PI; // BEFORE

-90+(salopeInRadian * 180) / Math.PI; // AFTER
```

---

The CSS already accomplishes what these lines do, so they're no longer needed.

```
line.style.top = yMid; // DELETE THIS
line.style.left = xMid - (distance/2); // DELETE THIS
```

---

Concatenate `px` unit after number.

```
line.style.width = distance; // BEFORE
line.style.height = distance + "px"; // AFTER
```

---

New JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/williamqin123/md3ywc16/

Comment: Thank you @downvote-flagger. Why not Math.atan2(y,x)? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_atan2.asp

Comment: @AllenBooTung Oops, I messed up. See updated answer and Fiddle.